# Longtable doesn't fit page size

Tags: longtable, tabularx, width

I have a longtable and it doesn't fit the page size. How to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, hmargin=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=4cm, headheight=3cm, footskip=2.5cm]{geometry}

    \begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
%\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|l|l|l|l|l|@{}}
\hline
№& Описание отклонения & Департамент & Идентифицированный риск & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Не идентифицированный риск 1} \\
\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & НИ Риск  \\
\cline{5-6}
        &           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & Объект 1 \\
\hline        
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I also tryed to use this code from the documentation but it still results in a table that is wider than the text width:

```
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|l|l|l|l|l|@{}}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently your columns are too wide because they do not wrap? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer How to wrap text in the columns?

Comment: I already suggested to the `\newcolumntype` command from the `array` package (and reading it's documenation) once (as a comment to another question where this wrapping was missing too) ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I guess it's a high time to read it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the size of a column by using `p<Xcm>`

```
\begin{longtable}{|p<1cm>|p<3cm>|p<3cm>|p<3cm>|p<3cm>|p<3cm>|}
```

Answer (score 6):

Package `ltablex` redefines the environment `tabularx` that it behaves like a `longtable`: pagebreaks are possible and header definitions too.

The `\hspace{0pt}` are needed for `pdflatex` and `xelatex`: TeX doesn't hyphenate the first word in a paragraph. However, LuaTeX does ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, hmargin=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=4cm, 
headheight=3cm, footskip=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2.2cm}|l|>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2cm}|X|l|}\hline
№& Описание отклонения & Департамент & Идентифицированный риск & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Не 
идентифицированный риск 1} \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline        
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But how to make it work with longtable? Because actually this table will be for 2-3 pages, and tabularx would be not very good for this.

Comment: It _is_  a longtable! Package `ltablex` is a combination of `longtable` and `tabularx`